# Compiler can't find graphics.h?

Tags: c++, bgi

How to solve below error...

fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'graphics.h': No such file or directory

is there a alternative for grahics.h file

Below is the code:

// f.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

```
#include "stdafx.h"


#include"graphics.h"
#include"dos.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "iostream.h"
#include "time.h"
#include"conio.h"
class set
{
public:
char u;int i;int z;char l;int b;long int t;int a;int x;int c;
char k;int v;int m; char w;int h[17];char q;
ins()
{
b=0;c=0;x=0;
}
void get()
{
v=0;
if(b==0)
{
goto k1;
}
if(b==1)
{
goto kk;
}
if(b==5)
{
goto ram1;
}
k1:
textcolor(14);
cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t  ::Child Production Presents::";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t\t :: CROREPATI ::";
delay(5000);
clrscr();
cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t::Terms And Conditions Apply::";
delay(5000);
kk:
clrscr();
cout<<"\n\n\n\n\t\t\t     :: INSTRUCTIONS ::";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t ::Use Only Num Keys For Options( 1 2 3 4 )::";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t::You Have Only Two Life Lines::";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t     :: A. Fifty-Fifty   B. Audience Vote ::";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t    ::Firstly Push ' Y ' Key For Life Line::";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t\t  :: THEN ::";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t::Use Keys A OR B For Life Lines::";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t    ::Don't Use Other Keys::";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t     ::Crorepati Game From Child Production::";
cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\tDeveloped By->!! KUMAR GAURAV JAIN !!";
delay(10000);
clrscr();
cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t::::::Audience Vote May Be Wrong::::::";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t\t::So Play Carefully::";
delay(5000);
ram1:
if(z==1)
{
goto ram;
}
else
{
clrscr();
cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t         :: WAIT ::";
delay(200);
if(v>=2)
{
v=v-1;
}
else
{
v=0;
}}
ram:
{
srand((unsigned) time(&t));
a=rand() % 50;
v=v+1;
for(m=2;m<=v;m++)
{
if(h[m]==a)
goto ram1;
}
h[v]=a;
if(v==16)
{
clrscr();
delay(2000);
cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t::Congratulations::\n";
cout<<"\n\t\t\t ::You Are The Winner Of This Game::";
delay(5000);
show2(); 
}}
if(a==0)
{
clrscr();
show();
show1();
gotoxy(1,17);
cout<<"Where Barmuda Triangle Is Suitated ?\n";
cout<<"1.Near America\t\t";
cout<<"2.Near WestIndies\n";
cout<<"3.Near Africa\t\t";
cout<<"4.Near Australia\n";
cout<<"DO YOU WANT TO USE LIFE LINES (Y/N)::";
cin>>w;
if(c==1&&x==1){
life1();goto p1;
}
if(w=='y'||w=='Y')
{
clrscr();
cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t\tA. Fifty-Fifty  B. Audience Vote";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t\tPlease Enter Your Choice (A/B)::";
cin>>q;
if(q=='a'||q=='A')
{ 
c1:if(c==1&&x==1)
{life1(); goto p1;}if(x==1&&c==0)
{cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t:: YOU CAN USE ONLY AUDIENCE VOTE ::";
goto c2;}
x=1;
cout<<"\t\t2.Near WestIndies";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t3.Near Africa";
cout<<"\n\n\t\tDo You Want To Use Another Life Line (Y/N)::";
cin>>q;
if(q=='y'||q=='Y')
{
goto c2;
}
else
{
cout<<"\n\n\t\tEnter Your Choice _____";
cin>>i;
}}
else if(q=='b'||q=='B')
{
c2:if(c==1&&x==1)
{life1();goto p1;}if(x==0&&c==1)
{cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t:: YOU CAN USE ONLY FIFTY-FIFTY ::";
goto c1;}c=1;
cout<<"\n\n\t\t1.Near America     ( 24% )";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t2.Near WestIndies ( 51% )";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t3.Near Africa         ( 20% )";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t4.Near Australia     ( 10% )"<<"\n\n";
cout<<"\n\n\t\tDo You Want To Use Another Life Line (Y/N)::";
cin>>q;
cout<<"\n\n";
if(q=='y'||q=='Y')
{
goto c1;
}
else
{
cout<<"Enter Your Choice 1 2 3 4_____";
cin>>i;
}}}
else if(w=='n'||w=='N')
{
cout<<"Enter Your Choice 1 2 3 4_____";
cin>>i;
}
p1:
if(i==2)
{
cout<<endl<<"\t\tYou Are Right";
delay(3000);
clrscr();
goto ram;
}
else
{
cout<<endl<<"\t\tSorry___You Are Wrong";
delay(3000);
}
clrscr();
cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\tRight Answer Is:: 2.Near WestIndies";
delay(2000);
show2();
}
if(a==1)
{
clrscr();
show();
show1();
gotoxy(1,17);
cout<<"\t\t2.Dr.Rajendra Prasad";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t3.Dr.Sarvapalli Radha Krishnan ";
cout<<"\n\n\t\tDo You Want To Use Another Life Line (Y/N)::";
cin>>q;
if(q=='y'||q=='Y')
{
goto c86;
}
else
{
cout<<"\n\n\t\tEnter Your Choice _____";
cin>>i;
}}
else if(q=='b'||q=='B')
{
c86:if(c==1&&x==1)
{life1();goto p43;}if(x==0&&c==1)
{cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t:: YOU CAN USE ONLY FIFTY-FIFTY ::";
goto c85;}c=1;
cout<<"\n\n\t\t1.Pt.Jabahar Lal Nehru         ( 12% )";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t2.Dr.Rajendra Prasad           ( 28% )";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t3.Dr.Sarvapalli Radha Krishnan ( 30% )";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t4.Dr.Bhagwan Das               ( 30% )"<<"\n\n";
cout<<"\n\n\t\tDo You Want To Use Another Life Line (Y/N)::";
cin>>q;
cout<<"\n\n";
if(q=='y'||q=='Y')
{
goto c85;
}
else
{
cout<<"Enter Your Choice 1 2 3 4_____";
cin>>i;
}}}
else if(w=='n'||w=='N')
{
cout<<"Enter Your Choice 1 2 3 4_____";
cin>>i;
}
p43:
if(i==3)
{
cout<<endl<<"\t\tYou Are Right";
delay(3000);
clrscr();
goto ram;
}
else
{
cout<<endl<<"\t\tSorry___You Are Wrong";
delay(3000);
}clrscr();
cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\tRight Answer Is:: 3.Dr.Sarvapalli Radha Krishnan";
delay(2000);
show2();
}
if(a==43)
{
clrscr();
show();
show1();
gotoxy(1,17);
cout<<"'SHOURYA' Award Started From_____?\n";
cout<<"1.1947\t\t\t"; 
cout<<"2.1950\n";
cout<<"3.1952\t\t\t";
cout<<"4.1955\n";
cout<<"DO YOU WANT TO USE LIFE LINES (Y/N)::";
cin>>w;
if(c==1&&x==1){
life1();goto p44;}
if(w=='y'||w=='Y')
{
clrscr();
cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t\tA. Fifty-Fifty  B. Audience Vote";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t\tPlease Enter Your Choice (A/B)::";
cin>>q;
if(q=='a'||q=='A')
{
c87:if(c==1&&x==1)
{life1();goto p44;}if(x==1&&c==0)
{cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t:: YOU CAN USE ONLY AUDIENCE VOTE ::";
goto c88;}  x=1;
cout<<"\t\t1.1947";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t4.1955";
cout<<"\n\n\t\tDo You Want To Use Another Life Line (Y/N)::";
cin>>q;
if(q=='y'||q=='Y')
{
goto c88;
}
else
{
cout<<"\n\n\t\tEnter Your Choice _____";
cin>>i;
}}
else if(q=='b'||q=='B')
{
c88:if(c==1&&x==1)
{life1();goto p44;}if(x==0&&c==1)
{cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t:: YOU CAN USE ONLY FIFTY-FIFTY ::";
goto c87;}c=1;
cout<<"\n\n\t\t1.1947 ( 40% )";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t2.1950 ( 31% )";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t3.1950 ( 14% )";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t4.1955 ( 15% )"<<"\n\n";
cout<<"\n\n\t\tDo You Want To Use Another Life Line (Y/N)::";
cin>>q;
cout<<"\n\n";
if(q=='y'||q=='Y')
{
goto c87;
}
else
{
cout<<"Enter Your Choice 1 2 3 4_____";
cin>>i;
}}}
else if(w=='n'||w=='N')
{
cout<<"Enter Your Choice 1 2 3 4_____";
cin>>i;
}
p44:
if(i==1)
{
cout<<endl<<"\t\tYou Are Right";
delay(3000);
clrscr();
goto ram;
}
else
{
cout<<endl<<"\t\tSorry___You Are Wrong";
delay(3000);
}
clrscr();
cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\tRight Answer Is:: 1.1947";
delay(2000);
show2();
}
if(a==44)
{
clrscr();
show();
show1();
gotoxy(1,17);
cout<<"How Many Awarded India Won In OLYMPIC 2004?\n";
cout<<"1.04\t\t\t";
cout<<"2.09\n";
cout<<"3.01\t\t\t";
cout<<"4.15\n";
cout<<"DO YOU WANT TO USE LIFE LINES (Y/N)::";
cin>>w;
if(c==1&&x==1){
life1();goto p45;}
if(w=='y'||w=='Y')
{
clrscr();
cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t\tA. Fifty-Fifty  B. Audience Vote";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t\tPlease Enter Your Choice (A/B)::";
cin>>q;
if(q=='a'||q=='A')
{
c89:if(c==1&&x==1)
{life1();goto p45;}if(x==1&&c==0)
{cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t:: YOU CAN USE ONLY AUDIENCE VOTE ::";
goto c90;}   x=1;
cout<<"\t\t1.04";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t3.01";
cout<<"\n\n\t\tDo You Want To Use Another Life Line (Y/N)::";
cin>>q;
if(q=='y'||q=='Y')
{
goto c90;
}
else
{
cout<<"\n\n\t\tEnter Your Choice _____";
cin>>i;
}}
else if(q=='b'||q=='B')
{
c90:if(c==1&&x==1)
{life1();goto p45;}if(x==0&&c==1)
{cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t:: YOU CAN USE ONLY FIFTY-FIFTY ::";
goto c89;}c=1;
cout<<"\n\n\t\t1.04 ( 40% )";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t2.09 ( 31% )";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t3.01 ( 14% )"; 
cout<<"\n\n\t\t4.15 ( 15% )"<<"\n\n";
cout<<"\n\n\t\tDo You Want To Use Another Life Line (Y/N)::";
cin>>q;
cout<<"\n\n";
if(q=='y'||q=='Y')
{
goto c89;
}
else
{
cout<<"Enter Your Choice 1 2 3 4_____";
cin>>i;
}}}
else if(w=='n'||w=='N')
{
cout<<"Enter Your Choice 1 2 3 4_____";
cin>>i;
}
p45:
if(i==3)
{
cout<<endl<<"\t\tYou Are Right";
delay(3000);
clrscr();
goto ram;
}
else
{
cout<<endl<<"\t\tSorry___You Are Wrong";
delay(3000);
}
clrscr();
cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\tRight Answer Is:: 3.01";
delay(2000);
show2();
}
if(a==45)
{
clrscr();
show();
show1();
gotoxy(1,17);
cout<<"Reliance Cup Is Related With______?\n";
cout<<"1.Hocky\t\t\t";
cout<<"2.Football\n";
cout<<"3.Table Tenis\t\t";
cout<<"4.Cricket\n";
cout<<"DO YOU WANT TO USE LIFE LINES (Y/N)::";
cin>>w;
if(c==1&&x==1){
life1();goto p46;}
if(w=='y'||w=='Y')
{
clrscr();
cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t\tA. Fifty-Fifty  B. Audience Vote";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t\tPlease Enter Your Choice (A/B)::";
cin>>q;
if(q=='a'||q=='A')
{
c91:if(c==1&&x==1)
{life1();goto p46;}if(x==1&&c==0)
{cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t:: YOU CAN USE ONLY AUDIENCE VOTE ::";
goto c92;}  x=1;
cout<<"\t\t3.Table Tenis";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t4.Cricket";
cout<<"\n\n\t\tDo You Want To Use Another Life Line (Y/N)::";
cin>>q;
if(q=='y'||q=='Y')
{
goto c92;
}
else
{
cout<<"\n\n\t\tEnter Your Choice _____";
cin>>i;
}}
else if(q=='b'||q=='B')
{
c92:if(c==1&&x==1)
{life1();goto p46;}if(x==0&&c==1)
{cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t:: YOU CAN USE ONLY FIFTY-FIFTY ::";
goto c91;}c=1;
cout<<"\n\n\t\t1.Hocky       ( 46% )";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t2.Football    ( 05% )";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t3.Table Tenis ( 04% )";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t4.Cricket     ( 45% )"<<"\n\n";
cout<<"\n\n\t\tDo You Want To Use Another Life Line (Y/N)::";
cin>>q;
cout<<"\n\n";
if(q=='y'||q=='Y')
{
goto c91;
}
else
{
cout<<"Enter Your Choice 1 2 3 4_____";
cin>>i;
}}}
else if(w=='n'||w=='N')
{
cout<<"Enter Your Choice 1 2 3 4_____";
cin>>i;
}
p46:
if(i==4)
{
cout<<endl<<"\t\tYou Are Right";
delay(3000);
clrscr();
goto ram;
}
else
{
cout<<endl<<"\t\tSorry___You Are Wrong";
delay(3000);
}
clrscr();
cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\tRight Answer Is:: 4.Cricket";
delay(2000);
show2();
}
if(a==46)
{
clrscr();
show();
show1();
gotoxy(1,17);
cout<<"Azra Cup Is Related With______?\n";
cout<<"1.Chess\t\t\t";
cout<<"2.Polo\n";
cout<<"3.Table Tenis\t\t";
cout<<"4.Cricket\n";
cout<<"DO YOU WANT TO USE LIFE LINES (Y/N)::";
cin>>w;
if(c==1&&x==1){
life1();goto p47;}
if(w=='y'||w=='Y')
{
clrscr();
cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t\tA. Fifty-Fifty  B. Audience Vote";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t\tPlease Enter Your Choice (A/B)::";
cin>>q;
if(q=='a'||q=='A')
{
c93:if(c==1&&x==1)
{life1();goto p47;}if(x==1&&c==0)
{cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t:: YOU CAN USE ONLY AUDIENCE VOTE ::";
goto c94;}  x=1;
cout<<"\t\t2.Polo";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t4.Cricket";
cout<<"\n\n\t\tDo You Want To Use Another Life Line (Y/N)::";
cin>>q;
if(q=='y'||q=='Y')
{
goto c94;
}
else
{
cout<<"\n\n\t\tEnter Your Choice _____";
cin>>i;
}} 
else if(q=='b'||q=='B')
{
c94:if(c==1&&x==1)
{life1();goto p47;}if(x==0&&c==1)
{cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t:: YOU CAN USE ONLY FIFTY-FIFTY ::";
goto c93;}c=1;
cout<<"\n\n\t\t1.Chess       ( 46% )";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t2.Polo        ( 05% )";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t3.Table Tenis ( 04% )";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t4.Cricket     ( 45% )"<<"\n\n";
cout<<"\n\n\t\tDo You Want To Use Another Life Line (Y/N)::";
cin>>q;
cout<<"\n\n";
if(q=='y'||q=='Y')
{
goto c93;
}
else
{
cout<<"Enter Your Choice 1 2 3 4_____";
cin>>i;
}}}
else if(w=='n'||w=='N')
{
cout<<"Enter Your Choice 1 2 3 4_____";
cin>>i;
}
p47:
if(i==2)
{
cout<<endl<<"\t\tYou Are Right";
delay(3000);
clrscr();
goto ram;
}
else
{
cout<<endl<<"\t\tSorry___You Are Wrong";
delay(3000);
}clrscr();
cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\tRight Answer Is:: 2.Polo";
delay(2000);
show2();
}
if(a==47)
{
clrscr();
show();
show1();
gotoxy(1,17);
cout<<"Who Told That 'A THING OF BEAUTY IS A JOY EVER' ?\n";
cout<<"1.John Milton\t\t\t";
cout<<"2.Lard Nelson\n";
cout<<"3.John Keets\t\t\t";
cout<<"4.Lard Milton \n";
cout<<"DO YOU WANT TO USE LIFE LINES (Y/N)::";
cin>>w;
if(c==1&&x==1){
life1();goto p48;}
if(w=='y'||w=='Y')
{
clrscr();
cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t\tA. Fifty-Fifty  B. Audience Vote";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t\tPlease Enter Your Choice (A/B)::";
cin>>q;
if(q=='a'||q=='A')
{
c95:if(c==1&&x==1)
{life1();goto p48;}if(x==1&&c==0)
{cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t:: YOU CAN USE ONLY AUDIENCE VOTE ::";
goto c96;} x=1;
cout<<"\t\t2.Lard Nelson";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t3.John Keets";
cout<<"\n\n\t\tDo You Want To Use Another Life Line (Y/N)::";
cin>>q;
if(q=='y'||q=='Y')
{
goto c96;
}
else
{
cout<<"\n\n\t\tEnter Your Choice _____";
cin>>i;
}}
else if(q=='b'||q=='B')
{
c96:if(c==1&&x==1)
{life1();goto p48;}if(x==0&&c==1)
{cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t:: YOU CAN USE ONLY FIFTY-FIFTY ::";
goto c95;}c=1;
cout<<"\n\n\t\t1.John Milton  ( 46% )";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t2.Lard Nelson  ( 05% )";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t3.John Keets   ( 04% )";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t4.Lard Milton  ( 45% )"<<"\n\n";
cout<<"\n\n\t\tDo You Want To Use Another Life Line (Y/N)::";
cin>>q;
cout<<"\n\n";
if(q=='y'||q=='Y')
{
goto c95;
}
else
{
cout<<"Enter Your Choice 1 2 3 4_____";
cin>>i;
}}}
else if(w=='n'||w=='N')
{
cout<<"Enter Your Choice 1 2 3 4_____";
cin>>i;
}
p48:
if(i==3)
{
cout<<endl<<"\t\tYou Are Right";
delay(3000);
clrscr();
goto ram;
}
else
{
cout<<endl<<"\t\tSorry___You Are Wrong";
delay(3000);
}clrscr();
cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\tRight Answer Is:: 3.John Keets";
delay(2000);
show2();
}
if(a==48)
{
clrscr();
show();
show1();
textcolor(14);
gotoxy(1,17);
cout<<"'LIGHT YEAR'Is Related With_______ ?\n";
cout<<"1.Distance\t\t\t";
cout<<"2.Speed\n";
cout<<"3.Energy\t\t\t";
cout<<"4.Light \n";
cout<<"DO YOU WANT TO USE LIFE LINES (Y/N)::";
cin>>w;
if(c==1&&x==1){
life1();goto p49;}
if(w=='y'||w=='Y')
{
clrscr();
cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t\tA. Fifty-Fifty  B. Audience Vote";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t\tPlease Enter Your Choice (A/B)::";
cin>>q;
if(q=='a'||q=='A')
{
c97:if(c==1&&x==1)
{life1();goto p49;}if(x==1&&c==0)
{cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t:: YOU CAN USE ONLY AUDIENCE VOTE ::";
goto c98;}    x=1;
cout<<"\t\t1.Distance";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t3.Energy";
cout<<"\n\n\t\tDo You Want To Use Another Life Line (Y/N)::";
cin>>q;
if(q=='y'||q=='Y')
{
goto c98;
}
else
{
cout<<"\n\n\t\tEnter Your Choice _____";
cin>>i;
}}
else if(q=='b'||q=='B')
{
c98:if(c==1&&x==1)
{life1(); goto p49;}
if(x==0&&c==1)
{cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t:: YOU CAN USE ONLY FIFTY-FIFTY ::";
goto c97;}c=1;
cout<<"\n\n\t\t1.Distance   ( 46% )";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t2.Speed      ( 05% )";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t3.Energy     ( 04% )";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t4.Light      ( 45% )"<<"\n\n";
cout<<"\n\n\t\tDo You Want To Use Another Life Line (Y/N)::";
cin>>q;
cout<<"\n\n";
if(q=='y'||q=='Y')
{
goto c97;
}
else
{
cout<<"Enter Your Choice 1 2 3 4_____";
cin>>i;
}}}
else if(w=='n'||w=='N')
{
cout<<"Enter Your Choice 1 2 3 4_____";
cin>>i;
}
p49:
if(i==1)
{
cout<<endl<<"\t\tYou Are Right";
delay(3000);
clrscr();
goto ram;
}
else
{
cout<<endl<<"\t\tSorry___You Are Wrong";
delay(3000);
}clrscr();
cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\tRight Answer Is:: 1.Distance";
delay(2000);
show2();
}}
show()
{
cout<<"1,000"<<endl;
cout<<"2,000"<<endl;
cout<<"3,000"<<endl;
cout<<"5,000"<<endl;
cout<<"10,000"<<endl;
cout<<"20,000"<<endl;
cout<<"40,000"<<endl;
cout<<"80,000"<<endl;
cout<<"1,60,000"<<endl;
cout<<"3,20,000"<<endl;
cout<<"6,40,000"<<endl;
cout<<"12,25,000"<<endl;
cout<<"25,00,000"<<endl;
cout<<"50,00,000"<<"\t\t\t\t\t\tA.Fifty-Fifty"<<endl;
cout<<"1,00,00,000"<<"\t\t\t\t\t\tB.Audience Vote"<<endl;
gotoxy(56,1);
cout<<"QUESTION NUMBER::"<<v<<endl;
}
show1()
{
if(v==1)
{
gotoxy(56,3);
cout<<"QUESTION FOR::1,000";
}
if(v==2)
{
gotoxy(56,3);
cout<<"QUESTION FOR::2,000";
}
if(v==3)
{
gotoxy(56,3);
cout<<"QUESTION FOR::3,000";
}
if(v==4)
{
gotoxy(56,3);
cout<<"QUESTION FOR::5,000";
}
if(v==5)
{
gotoxy(56,3);
cout<<"QUESTION FOR::10,000";
}
if(v==6)
{
gotoxy(56,3);
cout<<"QUESTION FOR::20,000";
}
if(v==7)
{
gotoxy(56,3);
cout<<"QUESTION FOR::40,000";
}
if(v==8)
{
gotoxy(56,3);
cout<<"QUESTION FOR::80,000";
}
if(v==9)
{
gotoxy(56,3);
cout<<"QUESTION FOR::1,60,000";
}
if(v==10)
{
gotoxy(56,3);
cout<<"QUESTION FOR::3,20,000";
}
if(v==11)
{
gotoxy(56,3);
cout<<"QUESTION FOR::6,40,000";
}
if(v==12)
{
gotoxy(56,3);
cout<<"QUESTION FOR::12,25,000";
}
if(v==13)
{
gotoxy(56,3);
cout<<"QUESTION FOR::25,00,000";
}
if(v==14)
{
gotoxy(56,3);
cout<<"QUESTION FOR::50,00,000";
}
if(v==15)
{
gotoxy(56,3);
cout<<"QUESTION FOR::1,00,00,000";
}
textcolor(14);
}
life1()
{
cout<<"\n\t\t:: YOU HAVE NO LIFE LINE ::";
cout<<"\n\t\t  Enter Your Choice _____";
cin>>i;
}
show2()
{
clrscr();
cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\tDO YOU WANT TO PLAY IT AGAIN (Y/N)::";
cin>>u;
if(u=='y'||u=='Y')
{
clrscr();
cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t   :: OK ::";
delay(1000);
cout<<"\n\n\t\t  :: Do You Want To Know The INSTRUCTIONS (Y/N) ::";
cin>>l;
if(l=='y'||l=='Y')
{
b=1;
}
else
{
b=5;
}
v=0;
x=0;c=0;
clrscr();
get();
}
else
{
clrscr();
cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t:: THANK YOU FOR PLAY IT ::";
delay(1000);
exit(0);
}}};
int main()
{
clrscr();
int gdriver=DETECT,gmode;
set s;
s.ins();
s.get();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not only have you not shown the line the causes the error, you haven't even told us what you need the header for. How can we tell you what alternatives you have? Where is the file located? Why are you including it?

Comment: @Jonathan Wood: i have added the source code of the same

Comment: Are you trying to port the application from Turbo C++ to Visual C++ ?

Comment: @yurymik: im complie a program in visual c++ 2010

Answer (score 4):

You have clearly told us the answer already: There is no file named graphics.h

However for an alternative, your alternative would be something like SDL or SFML.

Comment: Not necessarily. The file could simply be in a location the compiler didn't look.

Answer (score 3):

@Sanja Melnichuk appears to be correct, as a search of the web shows. Search for "visual cplusplus graphics.h not found". You get quite a few hits, many of which say things like:

- I think in the old DOS days, Borland C++ shipped a graphic library and the header file was "graphics.h". I am just curious - are you compiling old code using this modern compiler? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressvc/thread/198771fc-18dd-4c2b-b62a-8b0be6459942/
- Visual C++ doesn't support graphics.h, that's a Borland header I think. http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/39521-graphics-h-not-found.html
- You appear to be attempting to use old Borland libraries intended for use in 16bit DOS programs. Wrong compiler and wrong OS! http://forums.devshed.com/c-programming-42/problem-when-i-run-a-c-graphics-program-in-microsft-190109.html

It seems, to me, that the problems with your application go far beyond a mere missing header file. Your application appears to be attempting to do cursor addressing on a DOS-style console. There are libraries for that sort of thing, but the question you should be asking yourself is whether that sort of approach even makes sense here.

You can't expect to take code that operated in the old DOS environment and port it to a modern Windows environment without encountering some problems.

Comment: It seems as though you've just asked me to fix your code so that it'll work for you. I'm afraid that I cannot agree to do that, unless you're willing to pay my current hourly consulting rate. (I have paying clients for whom I am working today.) You've received plenty of help on this question; given the comments and pointers you've already received, surely, you can do a little more experimentation and research for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

No context whatsoever, so here's the most generic answer:

Try to find library that original developer meant to use, copy it to your machine and add its folder to the include-lookup paths.

Answer (score 2):

Hi i think you compile your program in borland c++ 3.11 but in visual studio there is no graphics.h you can use this [ms article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/03fd605a-5747-48ae-a1c7-6b37648258a3/) to draw in console window

Comment: @abhis sorry but there is no graphics.h in VS, you can use window dc to draw in window look my link.

Comment: Just one correction: bcpp 5.5 as for me =) there was turbo c 3.11 and it also had "graphics.h", but that was pure C, not C++ =)

Comment: @shybovycha Thanks i realy dont remember version it was six years ago )

Answer (score 0):

My advice for you is: use C++ Builder, and use **Form::Canvas** property to draw all your stuff. It's the easiest way as for me. VS doesn't have **graphics.h** - it was MSDOS one.